# html lint to other page's iframe

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

I have a page A with 2 links LinkA and LinkB
I have a page B with an iFrame iFrameB

I'd like to click on LinkA and go to page B and load in the iFrame a Url and if I click on LinkB do the same but load in the iFrame a different Url.

Is this possible?

EDIT

```
 Page A
 <a href="????">LinkA</a></div>
 <a href="????">LinkB</a></div>

 Page B
 <iframe width="100%" id="myFrame" src="http://www.default.html"></iframe>
```

From both links I'd like to open page B but with link a the iFram has to have a different src than when I click LinkB

Comment: probably this can help you better

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714630/clicking-on-iframe-open-new-tab-in-browser

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461071/referencing-another-page-and-change-the-iframe-content

Comment: Are you asking how to have two versions of Page B where the default `src` of an iframe element is different?

Comment: No, page B is the same, the only thing that has to change is the iFrame that has to be different when clicking on LinkA or LinkB

Comment: Thanks Sam but not. What I need is clear, the only thing is I don't know if I can do that...

Comment: @MikeJohnson — How is it "the same" if part of it is an iframe which is "different"?!

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is two different versions of Page B which are *almost* identical, but have a different value for one attribute.

You could achieve this by simply having a completely separate .html file for each version of page B.

The usual solution for this, however, would be to:

1. generate Page B using a server side programming language
2. put all the HTML in a template
3. make the value of the src attribute a value (e.g. `src="[% iframe_url | html %]`)
4. use your server side language to examine the query string and set the `iframe_url` variable conditionally

Then you could link to `/pageB?url=1` and `/pageB?url=2` (or however you want to express it).